# Permissions and Rights | How to allow creating Keywords, but not Categories?

Tags: 2011, authorization

I would like to give a certain group the ability to Read, Write Keywords in a given Category, but not the ability to create new Categories.

When setting up Rights, Scope and Permissions I understand that it is necessary to give `Category Management` Rights to a given group so that they can work with Categories and Keywords.  Following that, I grant this group Permissions to allow RWDL.  However, with this configuration the users in this group can create new Categories as well.

How would I go about giving the ability to do stuff with Keywords within a Category, but not create or manipulate Categories themselves?

Answer (score 11):

After a bit of experimentation it turns out that `Category Management` is a Right specifically to allow creating and modifying Categories, however it does not control the ability to work with Keywords within.  Permissions on the Category control what groups can RWDL Keywords.

So to prevent a group from being able to create or modify Categories while still allow working with Keywords within a given Category, do not grant the Category Management Right, but do grant Permissions on the given Category.  This seems contradictory to the documentation that Dylan points to in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely Nick, per the documentation

> To add a Keyword (to a Category or Keyword), you must have Category Management rights and Write permissions for the Category.

[[login required]](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_005JJFGGGD8858699HHFHJF#addHistory=true&filename=CMIM_AddingKeywordsToCategory.xml&docid=task_cmimE4D02A89C4AF4AFEB17D05DE53ACBCF9&inner_id=&tid=5b1663b6-0c15-4dfe-8c29-d152aff9b03f&query=Keyword%2520permissions&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_cmimE4D02A89C4AF4AFEB17D05DE53ACBCF9&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=Keyword%2520permissions&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1390133657948&currentQuery=Keyword%2520permissions&currentScope=)

Similar applies for editing/deleting keywords also.

> To move or delete a Keyword, you must have Category Management rights and Delete permissions for the Category.
>
> To cut and paste a Keyword, you must have Category Management rights and Write for the Category.

[[login required]](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_005JJFGGGD8858699HHFHJF#addHistory=true&filename=DeletingKeywords.xml&docid=task_27_2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_27_2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DKeyword%2520permissions&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1390133657948&currentQuery=Keyword%2520permissions&currentScope=)

Comment: +1 for providing the links to the docs.  However, your answer doesn't explain how you would prevent the creation of new Categories or modification of the name and other attributes of an existing Category, while still allowing to work with Keywords within.

Comment: Fair point Nick, my response here was initially entered into the comments but was a little long and ill-formatted. However, before reading your addition above - I would have been looking at the Event system as a definite possibility - of course, how it is managed (via users/user-groups/SGs etc.) depends on the business requirement and would likely be some sort of config file. Remember you need to work with ID's for keywords etc. so the management of specific categories/keywords needs to be considered for Content Porting - but seems your solution is more appropriate and out of the box indeed.